# Camera.open works on Android 4.2.2, but fails on 6.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I have 2 devices to test my app : an Acer v370 running Android 4.2.2, and a Samsung Galaxy S6 on 6.0.1

The app works fine on the Acer, but crashes instantly on the S6. I'm using 
`_camera = Camera.open(0);`
and debugging says it crashes at this point.

The error I get is :

```
09-15 11:24:33.491 15284-15284/com.user.qrReader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.user.qrReader, PID: 15284
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.user.qrReader/com.user.qrReader.MainActivity}:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4156)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4250)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
      at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:568)
      at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:405)
      at com.user.qrReader.CameraPreview.openCamera(CameraPreview.java:206)
      at com.user.qrReader.CameraPreview.captureStart(CameraPreview.java:288)
      at com.user.qrReader.QRReaderAppManager.onResume(QRReaderAppManager.java:208)
      at com.user.qrReader.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:187)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1286)
      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6987)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4145)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4250) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here are the permissions in my manifest :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I can't use camera2 because I have to keep the app compatible for at least android 4, and I don't know which direction to go. It must be something related to the new android but I can't find what. Any thoughts ?

EDIT : You can also do it manually, once the apk is installed, by going to settings>applications>application manager>{my app}>permissions> allow camera. Of course it's terrible and useless if you have the solution but it helped me for a bit while I was debugging so I'll leave it here.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: may be this is due to runtime permission in marshmallow

Comment: on 6.0 u need to check permission on runtime, and CAMERA is hard permission so u need to check it

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33498105/5165244) could be of some assistance.

Comment: Do you need example for check permission and save it?

Comment: @Rodriquez Yes thank you, that would be nice.

Comment: By the way if you could tell me what caused me to get downvoted, I would be happy to know to make my posts better in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Checking permission I created a separate class as below:

```
  public class MarshMallowPermission {

    public static final int RECORD_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
    Activity activity;

    public MarshMallowPermission(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public boolean checkPermissionForRecord(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissionForExternalStorage(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissionForCamera(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void requestPermissionForRecord(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)){
           Toast.makeText(activity, "Microphone permission needed for recording. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},RECORD_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public void requestPermissionForExternalStorage(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public void requestPermissionForCamera(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Camera permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for getting

```
MarshMallowPermission marshMallowPermission = new MarshMallowPermission(this);


public void getPhotoFromCamera() {

    if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForCamera()) {
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForCamera();
    } else {
        if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForExternalStorage()) {
            marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForExternalStorage();
        } else {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + getString(R.string.directory_name_corp_chat)
                            + File.separator
                            + getString(R.string.directory_name_images)
            );

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            try {
                mediaFile = File.createTempFile(
                        "IMG_" + timeStamp,  /* prefix */
                        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                        mediaStorageDir      /* directory */
                );
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it worked when I was using only one permission (I was using real time QRCode scanning so I didn't need record or external storage) but now it's not working : If I ask for 2 permissions I get <code>W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time</code>, with the typo ! I didn't find it in your code so I don't know where it's from. Anyway I can't ask for 2 permissions in a row :(

Comment: Solved, I made a new request following [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040355/how-to-check-the-multiple-permission-at-single-request-in-android-m) with all my permissions inside. The other request are then obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

"Note: if you app targets M and above and declares as using the CAMERA permission which is not granted, then atempting to use this action will result in a SecurityException."

This is really weird. Don't make sense at all. The app declares Camera permission using intent with action IMAGE_CAPTURE just run into SecurityException. But if your app doesn't declare Camera permission using intent with action IMAGE_CAPTURE can launch Camera app without issue.

The workaround would be check is the app has camera permission included in the manifest, if it's , request camera permission before launching intent.

Here is the way to check if the permission is included in the manifest, doesn't matter the permission is granted or not.

```
public boolean hasPermissionInManifest(Context context, String permissionName) {
final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
try {
    final PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
            .getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    final String[] declaredPermisisons = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
    if (declaredPermisisons != null && declaredPermisisons.length > 0) {
        for (String p : declaredPermisisons) {
            if (p.equals(permissionName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

}
return false;
```

}

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I assume I do "if (hasPermissionInManifest(...)) camera.open(0);" ?

Answer (score 0):

Camera class is deprecated since API 21.

[Camera class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

> recommend using the new android.hardware.camera2 API for new
>   applications.

Sadly I haven't experienced it yet, so I won't be able to help more.

Still a minor chance to take, try:

```
    Camera.open(); // Without argument
```

Regards

Comment: I edited the post, I can't use camera2 because it was introduced in API level 21. I tried with no argument with no success.

Answer (score 0):

this is in Activity. I check permissions and save it, change some of my permissions to permission about CAMERA. This is working example.

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_GET_ACCOUNTS = 101;
    private static final int REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 102;

 @TargetApi(23)
public void checkAudioPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        playerFragment.setupVisualizerFxAndUI();
        return;
    }
    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager
            .PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        playerFragment.setupVisualizerFxAndUI();
    }
}

@TargetApi(23)
public void checkGmailPermission() {
    if (isDeviceOnline()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            showGmailRecFragment(true);
            return;
        }
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager
                .PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
                    REQUEST_CODE_GET_ACCOUNTS);
            return;
        } else {
            showGmailRecFragment(true);
        }
    } else {
        Utils.showToast(this, getString(R.string.no_internet));
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]
        grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_GET_ACCOUNTS:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                showGmailRecFragment(true);
            } else {
                Utils.showToast(this, getString(R.string.accounts_permision_denied));
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                playerFragment.setupVisualizerFxAndUI();
            } else {
                Utils.showToast(this, getString(R.string.audio_permission_denied));
            }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            break;
    }
}
```

and this is on fragment when i want check permission again or if user denied it. Also this save the permissions

```
private void setupViewVisualizer() {
    if (!isLiveTv && !homeVideo.isVideoType()) {
        ((PlayerActivity) activity).checkAudioPermission();
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. I'm only saying this because I have a similar project, using the same API level and same camera.open() which works fine. The weird thing is in one all "Camera" occurrences are crossed, and not in the other and I don't know why. I'm sure if I found what the difference is the camera would work. I made some screenshots : i.imgur.com/LS5Y4v9.png As you can see the code is the same but Camera is crossed in the second project. i.imgur.com/jfWCE50.png here's the manifest as I suspect it has something to do with API levels and versions.

Comment: The two projects are very similar and were build from the same base, but one crashes and not the other. I found nothing on "why is camera crossed" as in "how to make Android Studio 'accept it' ", all the solutions are very complicated and avoiding the root of the problem (in my honest opinion, I may wrong)

Comment: Turns out one had "@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")" and not the other. It didn't solve the problem of why one is working and not the other but that's that